# How to automatically adjust div size to the image size within it in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a site that students can use to test their anatomical knowledge. The idea is to ask an anatomical structure randomly (for example the 'trachea') and to then click on the corresponding white box (a dotted div) and if the right one is chosen then this white box will disappear.

I can't seem to make the image shrink together with the div I placed it in. When I play around with the size of my browser window, I would like the div to always have the exact same dimensions as the image within it. Right now this isn't the case and the div is always visible (I have made the background color yellow to show what I mean).

I have tried putting the dive with the image in it inside another div called 'container' to see what I can do then. I have fooled around with that idea and then gave up on that. Perhaps this is a possibility but I am still a noob when it comes to web development/web design so I have no idea what to do with it.

(working in percentages and not pixels to make it compatible with multiple screen sizes)

[image]
[image]

```css
/*#container {
    position: fixed;
    border: solid black 6px;
    background-color: yellow;
    top: 10%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 40%;
    height: 70%;
}*/

#image {
    /*top: 10%;
    left: 3%;*/
    top: 30%;
    left: 38%;
    width: 23%;
    height: 50%;    
    background-image: url(trachea.jpg);
    background-color: yellow;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: solid black 3px;
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: cover;
}

#button_1 {
    top: 50%;
    left: 8%;
    width: 15%;
    height: 3%;
    /*width: 65px;
    height: 13px;*/
    border-style: dotted;
    position: relative;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!--<div id="container">-->
        <div id= "image">
            <div id= "button_1"></div>
        </div>
    <!--</div>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you approach it the wrong way. I would recommend to use the picture as background image of your div. You can then size the picture with the use of `background-size`. Alternativly use 'object-fit' and that in combination with either `contain, cover or scale-down`. However, in any case you should only declare width or height with the sue of `contain`. The other value will be sized to maintain the image ratio.

Comment: @tacoshy I have tried doing that but when I only assign a percentage to width, the height stays at zero.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this about what you trying to achieve. USe a div as a container with the width like 70% in this case. Means it will be 70% of the body in this case.

Then give the container the css delcration of `object-fit: contain;`. Means that the image has to take the whole with while containign the image aspect ratio.

Give the Image a width of `width: 100%;` to take the entire width of the parent. The height will automatically be sized to contain the image aspect ratio.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  object-fit: contain;
  border: 3px dotted black;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.text-box {
  height: 1em;
  width: 5em;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

#lung {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 20%;
  background-color: white;
}

#trachea {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 30%;
  background-color: white;
}

#larynx {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 55%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/8c4eB7FxIO6byYQ6UK8YdT6Fyck=/768x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc():format(webp)/respiratory_system-578d72f73df78c09e96906ff.jpg">
  <div class="text-box" id="lung">lung</div>
  <div class="text-box" id="trachea">trachea</div>
  <div class="text-box" id="larynx">larynx</div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make the parent div, `.outer`, maintain the same ratio as the image.

The `::before` section creates a pseudo element with the percentage of the image's ratio. In this case, the image used is 200px x 300px, so we'd use the following formula where we divide the height by the width and multiply it by 100%: `calc(300 / 200 * 100%)`.

Here is a website that visualizes this: https://ratiobuddy.com/

CSS tricks talks about it here: https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/

Making the button reposition though, that's a different problem. I tried seeing how to make its position responsive, but had no luck.

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="button"></div>
    <img class="image" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}

.outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

.outer::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: calc(300 / 200 * 100%); /* 300 = height, 200 = width. Replacing these values with your images will create the ratio needed */
}

.outer .inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px dashed #000;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
}
```